# Is To-One Relationships in Realm JavaScript only for one schema?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, realm

I am trying to insert my nested object to Realm with [To-One Relationships method](https://realm.io/docs/javascript/latest/#to-one-relationships), but I got an unexpected result where all value of my nested object is the same thing as the value from the first of my nested object that has been Relationship

**This is my schema looks like**

```
const PhotoSchema = {
  name: 'CUSTOMER_PHOTOS',
  properties: {
    base64: 'string'
  }
};

const TimeSchema = {
  name: 'CUSTOMER_TIMES',
  properties: {
    warranty: 'float',
    finish: 'float'
  }
};

const MainSchema = {
  name: 'CUSTOMERS',
  primaryKey: 'id',
  properties: {
    id: 'int',
    name: 'string',
    photo: {type: 'CUSTOMER_PHOTOS'},
    time: {type: 'CUSTOMER_TIMES'},
  }
};
```

**And try to insert some data like this**

```
import Realm from 'realm';

Realm.open({
  path: 'mydb.realm',
  schema: [PhotoSchema, TimeSchema, MainSchema]
})
.then((realm) => {

  realm.write(() => {
    realm.create('CUSTOMERS', {
      id: Date.now(),
      name: 'John',
      photo: {
        base64: 'ImageBase64'
      },
      time: {
        warranty: 31,
        finish: 7
      }
    })
  })

})
.catch((error) => {
  console.error(error)
});
```

The process of **inserting** data is **successfully BUT** I got **unexpected result** when successfully get that data from Realm

**Unexpected Result in console.log()**

```
{
  id: 1601335000882,
  name: "John",
  photo: {
    base64: "ImageBase64"
  },
  // This value is the same as PhotoSchema
  time: {
    base64: "ImageBase64"
  }
}
```

**I want to the actual result like this**

```
{
  id: 1601335000882,
  name: "John",
  photo: {
    base64: "ImageBase64"
  },
  time: {
    warranty: 21
    finish: 7
  }
}
```

I there anything wrong with my code? The [Documentation](https://realm.io/docs/javascript/latest/#to-one-relationships) is not too detail about the method, the explanation and the example is just like one word

### UPDATE:

I got an unexpected result only in the `console.log()` and if I try to access the property directly like `MY_DATA.time.warranty` the result is what I expected

#### The Answer is: No

[To-One Relationships method](https://realm.io/docs/javascript/latest/#to-one-relationships) is not only for one Schema, and **Thanks to** [Angular San](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7979754/angular-san) for showing an example of Inverse Relationships method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Try Inverse Relationships

I got an expected result with [Inverse Relationships](https://realm.io/docs/javascript/latest/#inverse-relationships) method. In this method, you have to add one property that connected to Main Schema and I want to call this a `combiner` property

```
const PhotoSchema = {
  name: 'CUSTOMER_PHOTOS',
  properties: {
    base64: 'string',
    combiner: {type: 'linkingObjects', objectType: 'CUSTOMERS', property: 'photo'}
  }
};

const TimeSchema = {
  name: 'CUSTOMER_TIMES',
  properties: {
    warranty: 'float',
    finish: 'float',
    combiner: {type: 'linkingObjects', objectType: 'CUSTOMERS', property: 'time'}
  }
};

const MainSchema = {
  name: 'CUSTOMERS',
  primaryKey: 'id',
  properties: {
    id: 'int',
    name: 'string',
    photo: 'CUSTOMER_PHOTOS',
    time: 'CUSTOMER_TIMES',
  }
};
```

Comment: Ohhh! I thought `Inverse Relationships` method only for a type `list` `[]`, and I am so confusing how to use that method because the example in the docs is not too detailed for me, and I am still bad at English, but, Very Thank You!